# Available screen height with UINavigationBar + UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, screen-size

So I'm developing an app with a UINavigationBar on top, and a UITabBar on the bottom. And I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is the real available height for the views. 
I've tried calculating the available screen height by calculating the UINavigationBar height and UITabBar height and subtract it from the main screen height, but that is still not the real size.

Here's my failed code for obtaining the available screen height:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
_screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
CGFloat tabBarHeight = _rootViewController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
UINavigationController* navigatior = _rootViewController.viewControllers[0];
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = navigatior.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat visibleHeight = _screenHeight - navigationBarHeight - tabBarHeight;

return visibleHeight;
```

Is there a clean way to know the real available screen size in an UINavigationBar + UITabBar based app??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate it and it changes depending on the iPhone. Your best bet and easiest path is to use the storyboard and embed both your navigation controller and tab bar directly in there. Once you have done that, you can use auto layout to pin your views to the bars and everything will be sized perfectly for you.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard, I love xib based apps x). Besides that, I use auto-layout like you say, which works perfectly in most of my view controller. Except in this one, where I have a UIScrollView, so I need to set the content size to the correct height. :/
Thanks for the response